# GKE - Automatic replacement of Instance Group Template

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

**Current Situation**: We're having a Kubernetes Cluster in Google (GKE). There is an instance group that refers an instance template defining the VMs.

**Problem**: Some days ago we had a spontaneous outage. I could find out that our instance group referred a new instance template, that was missing some access rights leading to that outage. Changing the instance template back to the original one solved the issue.

**What I'm still wondering**: We did neither change the template for the instance group nor did we create the instance template that was used.
I'm the only person managing the cluster, so I'm pretty sure that this happened automatically. How could this happen?

**Searching for a reason**:
I was researching on that topic but I could not find any related issues. I discovered three logs that might be interesting, but I cannot find a reason for that.

`gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-4f1a9017` is the new instance template created.

All three logs are direct subsequent logs:

Log1 - *ERROR* - `beta.compute.instanceGroupManagers.insert`:

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 6,
      "message": "The resource 'projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instanceGroupManagers/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-grp' already exists"
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "service-<ID>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "<IP_V6>",
      "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "google-api-go-client/0.5 GoogleContainerEngine/v1",
      "requestAttributes": {
        "time": "<TIMESTAMP>",
        "auth": {}
      },
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "compute.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "beta.compute.instanceGroupManagers.insert",
    "authorizationInfo": [
      {
        "permission": "compute.instanceGroupManagers.create",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instanceGroupManagers/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-grp",
          "type": "compute.instanceGroupManagers"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.instances.create",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instances/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-4f1a9017-0000",
          "type": "compute.instances"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.disks.create",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/disks/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-4f1a9017-0000",
          "type": "compute.disks"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.disks.setLabels",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/disks/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-4f1a9017-0000",
          "type": "compute.disks"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.subnetworks.use",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/regions/<MY_REGION>/subnetworks/default",
          "type": "compute.subnetworks"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.subnetworks.useExternalIp",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/regions/<MY_REGION>/subnetworks/default",
          "type": "compute.subnetworks"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.instances.setMetadata",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instances/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-4f1a9017-0000",
          "type": "compute.instances"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.instances.setTags",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instances/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-4f1a9017-0000",
          "type": "compute.instances"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.instances.setLabels",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instances/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-4f1a9017-0000",
          "type": "compute.instances"
        }
      }
    ],
    "resourceName": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instanceGroupManagers/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-grp",
    "request": {
      "name": "gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-grp",
      "instanceTemplate": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<MY_PROJECT>/global/instanceTemplates/<INSTANCE_TEMPLATE_ID>",
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/compute.instanceGroupManagers.insert",
      "targetSize": "0",
      "baseInstanceName": "gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-4f1a9017"
    },
    "response": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/error",
      "error": {
        "message": "The resource 'projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instanceGroupManagers/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-grp' already exists",
        "errors": [
          {
            "reason": "alreadyExists",
            "domain": "global",
            "message": "The resource 'projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instanceGroupManagers/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-grp' already exists"
          }
        ],
        "code": 409
      }
    },
    "resourceLocation": {
      "currentLocations": [
        "<MY_ZONE>"
      ]
    }
  },
  "insertId": "<INSERT_ID>",
  "resource": {
    "type": "gce_instance_group_manager",
    "labels": {
      "instance_group_manager_name": "gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-grp",
      "project_id": "<MY_PROJECT>",
      "location": "<MY_ZONE>",
      "instance_group_manager_id": "<INSTANCE_GROUP_MANAGER_ID>"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "<TIMESTAMP>",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "receiveTimestamp": "<TIMESTAMP>"
}
```

Log2 - *NOTICE* - `v1.compute.instanceGroupManagers.setInstanceTemplate`

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "service-<ID>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "<IP_V6>",
      "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "google-api-go-client/0.5 GoogleContainerEngine/v1",
      "requestAttributes": {
        "time": "<TIMESTAMP>",
        "auth": {}
      },
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "compute.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "v1.compute.instanceGroupManagers.setInstanceTemplate",
    "authorizationInfo": [
      {
        "permission": "compute.instanceGroupManagers.update",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instanceGroupManagers/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-grp",
          "type": "compute.instanceGroupManagers"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.instances.create",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instances/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-0000",
          "type": "compute.instances"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.disks.create",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/disks/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-0000",
          "type": "compute.disks"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.disks.setLabels",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/disks/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-0000",
          "type": "compute.disks"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.subnetworks.use",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/regions/<MY_REGION>/subnetworks/default",
          "type": "compute.subnetworks"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.subnetworks.useExternalIp",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/regions/<MY_REGION>/subnetworks/default",
          "type": "compute.subnetworks"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.instances.setMetadata",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instances/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-0000",
          "type": "compute.instances"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.instances.setTags",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instances/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-0000",
          "type": "compute.instances"
        }
      },
      {
        "permission": "compute.instances.setLabels",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "compute",
          "name": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instances/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-0000",
          "type": "compute.instances"
        }
      }
    ],
    "resourceName": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instanceGroupManagers/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-grp",
    "request": {
      "instanceTemplate": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<MY_PROJECT>/global/instanceTemplates/<INSTANCE_TEMPLATE_ID>",
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/compute.instanceGroupManagers.setInstanceTemplate"
    },
    "response": {
      "targetId": "8142394286096021440",
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/operation",
      "id": "<OPERATION_ID2>",
      "insertTime": "<TIMESTAMP>",
      "operationType": "compute.instanceGroupManagers.setInstanceTemplate",
      "targetLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instanceGroupManagers/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-grp",
      "zone": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>",
      "name": "<OPERATION_ID>",
      "progress": "0",
      "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/operations/<OPERATION_ID>",
      "status": "RUNNING",
      "user": "service-<ID>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "selfLinkWithId": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/operations/<OPERATION_ID2>",
      "startTime": "<TIMESTAMP>"
    },
    "resourceLocation": {
      "currentLocations": [
        "<MY_ZONE>"
      ]
    }
  },
  "insertId": "<INSERT_ID>",
  "resource": {
    "type": "gce_instance_group_manager",
    "labels": {
      "instance_group_manager_name": "gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-grp",
      "location": "<MY_ZONE>",
      "project_id": "<MY_PROJECT>",
      "instance_group_manager_id": "<INSTANCE_GROUP_MANAGER_ID>"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "<TIMESTAMP>",
  "severity": "NOTICE",
  "logName": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "operation": {
    "id": "<OPERATION_ID>",
    "producer": "compute.googleapis.com",
    "first": true
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "<TIMESTAMP>"
}
```

Log3 - *NOTICE* - `v1.compute.instanceGroupManagers.setInstanceTemplate`

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "service-<ID>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "<IP_V6>",
      "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "google-api-go-client/0.5 GoogleContainerEngine/v1"
    },
    "serviceName": "compute.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "v1.compute.instanceGroupManagers.setInstanceTemplate",
    "resourceName": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/zones/<MY_ZONE>/instanceGroupManagers/gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-grp",
    "request": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/compute.instanceGroupManagers.setInstanceTemplate"
    }
  },
  "insertId": "<INSERT_ID>",
  "resource": {
    "type": "gce_instance_group_manager",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "<MY_PROJECT>",
      "instance_group_manager_name": "gke-<MY_PROJECT>-default-pool-19b04905-grp",
      "instance_group_manager_id": "<INSTANCE_GROUP_MANAGER_ID>",
      "location": "<MY_ZONE>"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "<TIMESTAMP>",
  "severity": "NOTICE",
  "logName": "projects/<MY_PROJECT>/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "operation": {
    "id": "<OPERATION_ID>",
    "producer": "compute.googleapis.com",
    "last": true
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "<TIMESTAMP>"
}
```

Comment: did you manage to find a reason? I am facing the exact same problem. My template is switched with a new one without me doing anything.